# gcc: cannot find -lasound when crosscompiling

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, libasound

I try to crosscompile [this](https://gist.github.com/ghedo/963382) small program to my arm device, but get error:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lasound
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then i found libasound files in my target device and have copied to my folder /usr/lib but still no effect.
I use the commands:

```
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/include -I/usr/lib"
$CC -o play sound_playback.c $CFLAGS -lasound
```

I have installed **libasound2-dev** package on my Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and be able to compile the program on my native computer without any errors.

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION**
As Marc and John have said below, i just should use `-L` flag to set my library path. So my command line should be:

```
$CC -o play sound_playback.c $CFLAGS -L/usr/lib -lasound
```

Comment: Er, I don't think putting arm files in /usr/lib on an x86_64 machine is a good idea... Also, you probably meant `-L/usr/lib` but that's useless. Did you look into multiarch?

Comment: Marc is right, you should use -L (for libraries) and -I (for header files). Check where is the libasound.so[.XXX] and add this directory to the -L list of your compilation command.

Don't put "cross compiled files" in your /usr/lib/ directory, you may mess things up.

Comment: Oh, thank you guys! I just add -L/usr/lib to my command and it working!